# Need to rename .rtf files to match the contents of each file

Tags: windows, rename, batch-rename

I need to split, rename and change about 8000 files for a charity that I do work for. My question is if there is a program or code in Windows that I can use to change the file names to match the donor reference that is found inside each file (they all differ)?

I have tried a bulk rename utility but it seems to be to advanced for me. Please any help would be appreciated as I do not have the time to rename each file seeing as there is so many.

Comment: Welcome on Super User. It depends. If all the files have the same structure, maybe. A suggestion: do not rename them, if you have space copy them in a new location with their new names (in case your automation will fail, you will be able to find the original name). I suggest to create 2 new directories `Renamed` and `Processed` and to copy the file with the new name in the `Renamed` directory and to move the original one in the  `Processed` directory. So you will see your progress. Can you provide an example (of course without sensible data, with fantasy names) of the files you are working on?

Comment: It's all up to how the donor reference is present in the files. To have some success with what you want, there are 2 helpful conditions:
1. The donor name is at the same position within the file (let's say it starts at character 120) - in that case you could make a script to read from there and output that into the filename.
2. The donor name is preceded by a specific string (lets say somewhere in the file there's a string like donor = 'his name'). In this case, that can be an identifier that could help you output donor name.

Comment: You need to post some sample data to get any useful, non-generic answers.  **NOTE**: it seems as if these files contain confidential private information.  Change **ALL** identifying information (names, id numbers, addresses, phone numbers, etc etc etc) **before** posting a sample.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to rename them with a nifty program called a-pdf renamer where it was possible to record macros than ran per each file. I obviously had to change them all to PDF, but it worked in the end.